# Downloading a file using AJAX GET from Spring Service

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, spring, file-upload

I'm trying to implement a Service that automatically starts a download with the requested file.

This is my AJAX call:

```
function downloadFile(fileName) {
  $.ajax({
    url : SERVICE_URI + "files/" + fileName,
    contentType : 'application/json',
    type : 'GET',
    success : function (data)
    {
      alert("done!");
    },
    error: function (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  });
}
```

and this is my Spring Service method GET:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/files/{file_name}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public void getFile(@PathVariable("file_name") String fileName,
                    HttpServletResponse response) {
    try {
        // get your file as InputStream
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream( fileName + ".csv" );
        InputStream is = fis;
        // copy it to response's OutputStream
        ByteStreams.copy(is, response.getOutputStream());
        response.setContentType("text/csv");
        response.flushBuffer();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        throw new RuntimeException("IOError writing file to output stream");
    }

}
```

When my client requests the existing file from the server, the AJAX `success()` method is executed but the file is not even downloading. Am I doing anything wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Don't use ajax, just set window.location.href to the url of the file and set the http content disposition header in your server script to force the browser to save the file.

```
function downloadFile(fileName) {
  window.location.href = SERVICE_URI + "files/" + fileName;
}
```

Comment: Which are these headers you are talking about?

Comment: Works perfectly!
Just in case someone wonders how I set the *http* headers in my Server:

`response.setContentType("application/x-download");`



`response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fileName);`

Comment: @Musa what if my server validates the jwt token in header? Is there a way to add headers in window.location.href ? How to handle this issue?

Comment: If you have to set headers, then you'll have to use ajax.