# File download through ajax

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, ajax, spring

I need to download file from server via ajax. The problem is that the file is not stored on server. My java-based backend automatically generates file from request parameters and returns it in response body:

```
  @RequestMapping(value = "/download", method = RequestMethod.GET)
  public void download(@RequestParam String description, @RequestParam Long logId, HttpServletResponse response) {
    try {
      InputStream fileContent = // getting file as byte stream
      response.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_VALUE);
      response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=file.zip");
      ServletOutputStream responseOutputStream = response.getOutputStream();
      org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copy(fileContent, responseOutputStream);
      response.flushBuffer();
    } catch (IOException e) {
      logger.error("Attempt to download file failed", e);
    }
  }
```

So i need to handle it and allow user to download file. 
My client side contains this:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: "/download",
  data: {
    description: "test",
    logId: 123
  },
  success: function(data) {
    var blob = new Blob([data]);
    var link = document.createElement('a');
    link.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    link.download = "file.zip";
    link.click();
  }
})
```

Controller returns file, but then nothing happens. What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't make an AJAX call, but rather set the window's href to point to URL for downloading the file.  Then change the content type of the response to `application/x-download` and set the header of the response to be `Content-disposition`:

```
response.setContentType("application/x-download");
response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fileName);
response.flushBuffer();

function download(fileName) {
    window.location.href = "/download?description=test&logId=123";
}
```

Also, have a look at [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27785819/downloading-a-file-using-ajax-get-from-spring-service) which addresses a similar problem to the one you have.

Comment: Okay, but what do i need to do if i want post request instead of get and pass looong string parameter?

Comment: This method won't work for POST.  But why are you changing your question now?

Comment: Your answer is working perfectly in my specific case. I'm just trying to dig deeper.

Answer (score 4):

For those looking a more modern approach, you can use the `fetch API`. The following example shows how to download a `PDF` file. It is easily done with the following code.

```
fetch(url, {
    body: JSON.stringify(data),
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
    },
})
.then(response => response.blob())
.then(response => {
    const blob = new Blob([response], {type: 'application/pdf'});
    const downloadUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    const a = document.createElement("a");
    a.href = downloadUrl;
    a.download = "file.pdf";
    document.body.appendChild(a);
    a.click();
})
```

I believe this approach to be much easier to understand than other `XMLHttpRequest` solutions. Also, it has a similar syntax to the `jQuery` approach, without the need to add any additional libraries.

Of course, I would advise checking to which browser you are developing, since this new approach won't work on IE. You can find the full browser compatibility list on the following [link][1].

**Important**: In this example I am sending a JSON request to a server listening on the given `url`. This `url` must be set, on my example I am assuming you know this part. Also, consider the headers needed for your request to work. Since I am sending a JSON, I must add the `Content-Type` header and set it to `application/json; charset=utf-8`, as to let the server know the type of request it will receive.

**Important**: Sending parameters to a 'GET' request using the `fetch API` would need to use `URLSearchParams` interface.

Comment: Yeah this works perfectly, you can just do a normal GET request through ajax and on the back end you have to ensure that you send a file as a response with the appropriate content-type (application/pdf for example). I used Axios in my case and I set `responseType` to Blob and it automatically uses the provided Content-Type. It also does work if you set the "click" button ahead of time in case you wish to reuse it for multiple downloads.