# Downloaded by ajax excel file is corrupted

Tags: javascript, excel, spring-boot

I have a Spring Boot web application, which generate Microsoft Excel file with extention `.xlsx`.

If I try to download file from browser calling the `localhost:8080/report/stats` it a returns correct file and I always can open it one successfully.

But, when I download a file from web page by click on button I get a bad file and I can't open it one.

I have the following part on JS:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'report/stats',
    type: "GET",
    success: function (data) {
        var link = document.createElement('a');
        link.download = 'report.xlsx';
        link.href = 'data:,' + data;
        link.click();
    }
});
```

Controller:

```
@GetMapping("stats")
public ResponseEntity downloadStatsReport() throws IOException {
    return fileResponse(excelReportService.create(new StatFilter()));
}

private ResponseEntity fileResponse(File report) throws IOException {
    InputStreamResource resource = new InputStreamResource(new FileInputStream(report));
    return ResponseEntity.ok()
            .contentLength(report.length())
            .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, "attachment;filename=" + report.getName())
            .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)
            .body(resource);
}
```

Why downloading from browser works well and not works from JS?

Open file error:

[image: Open file error]

YES has been clicked:

[image]

NO has need clicked:

[image]

Comment: Hope this answer solve your problem. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36134095/file-download-through-ajax

Comment: @DharmaSaputra, thanks for response, I have tried the solution and it really works, but using the following solution it is not possible to know when the request is completed or no...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to download a valid file using the following code

```
function download(fileName) {
    window.location.href = "/download?description=test&logId=123";
}
```