# How to make a loader using ajax while file is converting

Tags: jquery, node.js, ajax

I'm trying to make a loader while file is converting.

I am working with Nodejs and I am converting a file, I am using AJAX Get request for my API to call then it starts converting file when its finished using content disposition file is available for download, for this reason I want to make a loader for user to wait.

But I am facing a problem that how to put a check on AJAX success call while my Nodejs request send res data so

AJAX code

```
function download()
{
      var id ='{{@root.meta.id}}';
      $.ajax({

             url: "/getdownload",
             data: { id: id },
              type: "GET",
              dataType: "json",
              beforeSend: function () {
              $("#loading_img1").css('display', 'inline');
              },
              success: function (data) {
                alert("Success");               

                $("#loading_img1").css('display', 'none');
              },//success
              error: function (jqxhr, status, exception) {
                alert('Sorry Try Again.', exception);
              },//error
              always: function (xhr, status) {
                alert("The request is complete!");
              }//always
            });
 }
```

Nodejs code:

```
...
fs.readFile('/Users/apple/Desktop/'+output, function (err, content) {
          if (err) {
            res.writeHead(400, {
              'Content-type': 'text/html'
            })
            console.log(err);
            //res.redirect('/');
          } else {
            //specify Content will be an attachment
            res.setHeader('Content-disposition', 'attachment; filename=' + output);
            res.end(content);
          }
});
```

The problem is it send response in data, I am unable to solve this problem, I want that when it makes a call loader starts before serving file loader ends and download file through this method.

**Edit:**
You can assume that when someone is trying to convert a file its shows a waiting time/percentage conversion thats what I want to achieve. Thanks

Comment: The general consensus is that returning your file in the ajax response doesn't work because javascript can present a save-as/download dialog.  A quick look at SO answers are divided into two - save the file server-side then redirect to that file, or redirect to the processing file.   Neither use ajax to *download* the file.   Example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27785819/downloading-a-file-using-ajax-get-from-spring-service

Comment: I was using window location before but my boss told me to do like this :( you can assume that when someone is trying to convert a file its shows a waiting time/percentage conversion thats what I want to achieve. Thanks

Comment: If your boss is telling you how to achieve unachievable results then they need to guide you.  You cannot save to file from Javascript alone.  It *requires* a redirect or new tab to open the content that automatically downloads.  It's also possible to create a download link and click it, but not in all browsers and don't expect it to always be possible.  Automatic downloads from code are blocked for a good reason.

Comment: Also, don't go down the route of trying to show time remaining or percent done as that's a LOT more complicated.  I suggest a simple spinner type graphic that shows the process is busy.

Comment: 1) show in-progress animation 2) make ajax call 3) on the server, build the file, and save **to the server** 4) return that the file is "ready" with a link to the (temp) file 5) location.href to the newly generated file.   Solves all your issues.

Comment: Thank you @freedomn-m, solved my problem.You can post this below I will mark it correct.

Comment: Glad you got it sorted - it's essentially a summary of the marked duplicate (and probably many others) (so doesn't deserve an answer, sorry)

Answer (score -2):

By what i understand, try moving your loader code from `success` to `completed`. like

...

```js
...

                      beforeSend: function () {
                      $("#loading_img1").css('display', 'inline');
                      },
                      success: function (data) {
                        alert("Success");               
                        console.log(data) //logs data from server
                      },
                      error: function (jqxhr, status, exception) {
                        alert('Sorry Try Again.', exception);
                      },//error
                      always: function (xhr, status) {
                        alert("The request is complete!");
                      }//always
                    }),
                    completed: () => $("#loading_img1").css('display', 'none');

...
```

`completed`runs after `success`

Comment: Completed runs *immediately* after success (or error).  It has nothing to do with whether something else has completed on the server.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, but I was not referring to a completion on the server.

Comment: Yes sorry that was worded incorrectly.  This has nothing to do with the OP's problem.  They're trying to get *and save* the contents with Javascript, which you can't do with an AJAX call.

Comment: @Archer this is not a duplicate question. I am trying to make loader for user to wait. Kindly remove duplication.

Comment: @adamwood  Okay - you cannot do what you are describing.  Look at the linked question for a working solution.

Comment: @Archer I was using window location before but my boss told me to do like this :( you can assume that when someone is trying to convert a file its shows a waiting time/percentage conversion thats what I want to achieve. Thanks

Comment: @adamwood Please see my comment under the question.

Comment: @Archer THANK YOU SO MUCH. :D

Answer (score -2):

**complete** executes after either the success or error callback were executed.

Maybe you should check the second parameter complete offers too. It's a String holding the type of success the ajaxCall had.

The different callbacks are described a little more in detail here 
https://jquery.com/#options

Also as you are working with file stream so comlete is thing which will be called finally at the end